# Build a link with variables in a views custom text using '%5B' characters

Tags: views

I use the [FillPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/fillpdf) module. Data from a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) are used to generate a pdf thanks to a url, as explained in the **FillPDF** documentation.

```
my_site.com/fillpdf?fid=95&webform[nid]=119&webform[sid]=[submission:sid]&download=1
```

numbers are those I use, yours can whatever.
I wrote such a url in the confirmation message, so that the user can download its submission results in a file. It works fine.

I would now like to allow an admin to do the same when consulting the submission result tab.
I saw this table was a view. I edited the view so I could display the proper [nid] and [sid] I need within the url.
Then I hid them form display and called them in a Global Text field. I thought I could write my url placing my numbers where i needed them, using '%5B' instead of brackets (which I need for the replacement patterns)

```
my_site/fillpdf?fid=[field_fillpdf_form_info]&webform%5Bnid%5D=[nid]&webform%5Bsid%5D=[sid]&download=1
```

Halas! these weird '%5B' and '%5D' are not interpreted. Did anyone come upon this problem already?

Comment: It actually works without needing the brackets. My mistake sorry.